# How can I export custom Salesforce Objects (fields and tables)

Tags: salesforce, apex-data-loader

I am using Dataloader to export data out of a salesforce instance.

I am having two problems.

1. Custom tables do not appear in the list of objects to select. Plenty of other objects do appear - and I can export them to a CSV file. But no custom tables are shown.
2. Some tables have custom fields which are not exported - but only certain custom fields. The Opportunity table has a ton of custom fields, the vast majority of which are exported, but some are not.

I have very little experience with salesforce, I'm simply trying to get this data out into a database to work with it.

I use data loader to export data. The application works - it will connect to, and export data from the salesforce instance, but it will not export custom tables - or some custom fields in standard tables.

I was expecting Dataloader to display all the tables, and export all the fields

Answer (score 0):

Data Loader respects user permissions. If there's object or field but you're not authorised to see it - attempt to force include it in say SOQL query will throw same error as if you've mistyped the field name. As far as you're concerned - there's no such field in the database, go away.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_fields

You will have to talk with your System Administrator to tick a bunch of checkboxes on your Profile / Permission sets to make these tables and columns at least readable. If they'll say "no" because it'd give you too much power in the application... They may consider giving you another special "see all but readonly" user and you'd login to data loader as that?

P.S.

If the fields come from managed package - you may need a package license too.